# Convergence of this summation

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that for some constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$|f(t)| \leq \frac{C}{1+t^2}$$

for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there anything that can be concluded about the series

$$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}f(x+2k\pi)$$?

Comment: Yes, it's convergent for every $x$.

Comment: Can you help me see why?

Comment: It's a very straightforward comparison using the fact that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}} k^{-2} < \infty$. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: oh my god. i overlooked that one. thanks

Comment: @user296602 Please consider posting an answer to "complete" the question.

Comment: I have another question. Does it converge uniformly?

Comment: @SumRay: the given series is uniformly convergent to a continuous and bounded function over $\mathbb{R}$. The reason is still the same, $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^*}\frac{1}{k^2}<+\infty$.

Comment: It might be interesting to compute (from the Poisson summation formula) and explicit form for your series in the $f(t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ case.

Comment: You should get $\frac{1}{2}\,\text{Re}\coth\left(\frac{1+ix}{2}\right)$.